# shell script to check time drift

Tags: regex, shell

I need a script to check time difference between local servers and internet time.

To obtain local time I'd run something like

```
    [root@check ~]# ntpdate -q timeserver
server x.x.x.x, stratum 1, offset -0.034282, delay 0.04228
11 Dec 12:04:21 ntpdate[62714]: adjust time server x.x.x.x offset -0.034282 sec
```

from above output we could grab,

> 11 Dec 12:04:21

To obtain internet time I'd like to run something like

```
    [root@check~]# curl http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
2015-12-11T12:04:43+00:00
```

from above output we could grab,

> 2015-12-11T12:04:43

Then echo ("Time drift detected"), if local time > internet time

I'm a newbie to shell scipting and your support is appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: ntpdate is not 'local time' and it also just told you what the drift was.

Comment: @pvg Thanks for your response. I'm aware that ntpdate is not local time, however our ntp server is not synced via public internet ntp pools, the time is set manually, therefore it is local when compared to internet time.

Comment: Ok, then why not query something like time.nist.gov (or whatever is more appropriate locally) over ntp? ntp is designed specifically for this, http is not.

Comment: @pvg that is absolutely true. However we block ntp from our perimeter firewalls, that is why I had to resort to something like JSON api which would get delivered via http/https.

Comment: Well. Not sure what to tell you since the whole thing sounds a bit nuts. ntp will do all of this stuff for you, including a) making sure the the queries are accurate b) keeping all your clocks in sync c) _computing and tracking drift for accurate disconnected operation_  all you have to do is let one ntp server somewhere talk to a real time server.

Comment: @pvg I totally agree with what you're saying. The trouble is that my managers like to maintain distance from public ntp servers due to recent surge in exploits directed towards ntp.

Comment: You're not going to get an accurate reading of drift over http. You are better off working to secure your NTP setup, your managers might enjoy this http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/auth-ntp.cfm (documents by snail mail! authentication!).

Comment: @pvg thanks for the info.We are not after precision, but rather consistency. We are facing couple of issues with our local ntp server (last time drift during an incident was 10 hours). I just need a script to compare local time to internet time and then notify if there is a significant change (more than 5mins).

Comment: Right but you seem to care about, say, security. http call to timeapi is spoofable, aside from the fact that timeapi.org appears to be run by some random person on heroku.

Comment: curl -s time.nist.gov:13  is marginally better if, again, completely unauthenticated.

Comment: @pvg that's true, however I won't use timeapi as the time source for our local servers but rather a baseline to detect anomalous behaviour of our own servers.

Comment: how can you do that if you can't trust timeapi? it doesn't seem any better  (it's actually worse) than sticking a post it on your monitor that says 'remember to check ntp server time vs what's on my phone after morning coffee'

Comment: @pvg I'd have to disagree there, it most definitely is not worse than a post it note :) purely because I don't know who would spoof timeapi, even if they did, all I would get is notification saying "Time drift detected". In any case I'd check other time sources (phone, wall clock, watch... other time servers) before I do anything. The most important thing is getting a notification when everything is legit.